# CTkScrollableDropdown, how to change dynamically the values

Tags: python, dropdown, customtkinter

I want to change the Values with the command

self.input_itemsearch.bind("", keyboard_iteamsearch)

It should refresh the dropdown by every single keyrelease.

My problem is that the dropdown don´t update and the Docu from the CTkScrollableDropdown doesn´t help me.

I builded it with the normal combobox from customtkinter but i cant use it because i have to much values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.